# Accessing an pscustomobject with dot notation in a string

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Given this piece of code

```
$Object = @"
{
    "Item1":{
        "Subitem1":{
            "Subsubvalue":"Value"
        }
    },
    "Value1":"value1"
}

"@ | ConvertFrom-Json
```

and given the following string (that I don't know at runtime, I've just got a string with an object path)

```
$String = "$Object.Item1.Subitem1.Subsubvalue"
```

I am trying to do the following - but I can't find a way to make it work

```
PS C:\> $Substring = $string.substring(8)
PS C:\> $Object.$Substring 
Value
```

My ultimate goal is to get to modify the contents of that

```
PS C:\> $Object.$Substring = "something else"
```

Obviously $substring approach doesn't work, nor the other approaches I've tried.

Comment: For me, its not clear what you want to achive. There are multiple outcomes that I can imagine with multiple ways to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Invoke-expression to handle this as it will parse the string passed to it as if it was a command.

So you can do the following:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "$string"
```

This will return:

```
Value
```

So you can then do:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "$String = `"Something else`""
```

Which will set the value to "Something else".

Answer (score 1):

`Invoke-Expression` is no better than `eval` in other languages. It's far too likely to do something undesired/unexpected because it evaluates the given string as code. I would not recommend going that route unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Try a recursive function instead:

```
function Get-NestedItem {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        $InputObject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=1)]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        [string]$Path = '',

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2)]
        [string]$Delimiter = '.'
    )

    if ($Path) {
        $child, $rest = $Path.Split($Delimiter, 2)
        Get-NestedItem $InputObject.$child $rest
    } else {
        $InputObject
    }
}

$Object = ...
$Path   = 'Item1.Subitem1.Subsubvalue'

Get-NestedItem $Object $Path
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach! I'll try it out. (and I see your point about the security risk too)

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using a dedicated function to do this work rather than depending on `Invoke-Expression`. Solutions like this are detailed in  [this tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875328/problems-parsing-accessing-nested-json-hashtable-data-via-variables-in-power/52175236#52175236).